# WPF binding object to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I need to bind objects stored in a list to a ComboBox. Basically I need to update the list of ComboBox items dynamically for a continuous set of operations. This is my code:

```
class Broker
    {
    public List<Item> FillComboBox()
    {
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Sklad";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            connection.Open();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Item item = new Item();

                item.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"].ToString());
                item.Znacka = reader["Znacka"].ToString();
                item.Model = reader["Model"].ToString();
                item.Typ = reader["Typ"].ToString();
                item.Farba = reader["Farba"].ToString();
                item.Mnozstvo = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Mnozstvo"].ToString());
                item.NakupnaCena = Convert.ToDouble(reader["NakupnaCena"].ToString());
                item.PredajnaCena = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PredajnaCena"].ToString());

                itemList.Add(item);
            }
            return itemList;
        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(eX.Message);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

and I call it in main like this:

```
private void FillComboBox()
    {
        cmbItems.ItemsSource = broker.FillComboBox();
    }
```

and it apparently does nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check to make sure that FillCombobox is actually returning a list with anything in it.

Comment: As a test, I would add item.ToString() instead, just to make sure the your comboBox is working with default types. So try itemList.Add(item.ToString()); It may be that your combobox simply doesn't know how to render your Item type.

Comment: Show the XAML for you ComboBox

Comment: oh my compiler was confused by actions that I made... simple reopen solution helped but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is right but my compiler was rly confused so that was the issue. Simple reopen solution helped!